# How To submit Google Spreadsheets via Google Api or via Curl

Tags: curl, google-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I tried to submit it via ajax but it displays cross origin request blocked..! so I can't post via ajax. 
so I am finding way to post it via Curl or using Google API. Any one have idea then please suggest me or give me example.

Below is what I tried via ajax. But not working. Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows ..they are now allowed

```
$.ajax({

            url: '<?php echo  "http://docs.google.com/....../forms/d/1Oa2nzHMY_KEY____MY___URL_ORC8HUVcxpTgc/viewform" ;?>',
            type:'POST',    
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType:'xml',
            catch:false,
    data:{'entry.1568082623':'yes','entry.102213609':'test'},
          success: function(data){
                alert('ok');
                $('#original_form_id').submit();
            }
        })

     }
```

and then after I am finding solution to post it via curl or using Google API.

Comment: https://gridspree.io (free for low volumes, api that will update from JavaScript)

For curl, a few people have done this, did you see:
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-spreadsheet-api%5D+curl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you have to construct the curl command first and then execute it in shell.

The `curl` command can be as:

```
curl https://docs.google.com/forms/d/<form-id>/formResponse -d ifq -d <field-name>=<field-value> -d submit=Submit
```

Here is the [link](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2014/07/30/submit-google-forms-by-curl-command/) to explain how it can be done.

Hope that helps!